# ClearCase - how to discard versions .../0 from find output

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I would like to get a list of all versions since some date but excluding versions .../0

But this ...

```
cleartool find \frdcc_hyb_sw\ -version "{created_since(20190201) && !(version(.../0))}"  -print
```

gives me error:

```
cleartool: Error: Malformed branch pathname: "\...".
```

Am I doing somethig wrong or this is simply not possible?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`version(.../0)` should reference a *branch* version, not directly the version number itself, as part of [version selector](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/bg/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/version_selector.htm).
The `...` is an ellipsis wildcard.

So:

```
!(version(.../myBranch/0))
```

Since there is not wildcard for the branch, you might as well remove the version selector, and grep the result to exlude any `/0` version.

```
ct find \frdcc_hyb_sw\ -version "{created_since(20190201)}" -print | grep -v "/0"
```